# function in c++ why my compiler didn't recognize the error()

Tags: c++

getting error using error() function in c++.

my problem is when i wanted to include the error() function to my code i get compilation errors.
it seems that the compiler does not recognize this function.

```
int some_function(){
        double input{0};
        cin>>input;
        if(!cin){
        error("couldn't read double in 'some_function()'");

        return -1;
        }
```

i expected the message "couldn't read double in 'some_function()'" when i input for example a string.

Comment: C++ doesn't have a standard `error` function.  What `error` function are you trying to use?

Comment: What is the compilation error?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: Perhaps #error directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `error` function in the C++ standard library. Your compiler doesn't "recognize" this function because it doesn't exist.

Why do you think there should be such a function?

If you want to print an error message in C++, the usual method is to use the `cerr` stream:

```
std::cerr << "couldn't read double in 'some_function()'\n";
```

Comment: i am a littel bit new in c++ i have remarque that many programmer use error() function i i thought it is a standard function. i have tried cerr it did the tazsk very well i thank you melpomene and the others for the question about compile time errors they occur when the compiler try to covert your program into an object file

Comment: after some researche i have found that error() function have to be implemented by the programmer and have to include in its body { throw runtime_error( a name of string ...);} and it is a void function that have a string type argument and that trow run time error not compile time error thanks!